# If we were to setup a cannabis store online hosted in Colorado (or any other state), can we legally serve California?

Tags: united-states, medical-marijuana, us-federal-government

My main question is that since cannabis is still prohibited federally, would be illegal for cannabis sales data and payment processing to cross state lines?

Comment: What does it mean for sales data to cross state lines? I assume you are talking about internet sales and electronic payment processing, but you should clarify what you are really asking. States do not require customers to be local residents, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: No non-cash payment system would do business with a company doing that if they learned it was a marijuana business and there is probably TOS language that says that in their merchant contract. An inability to pay electronically would be a huge problem with this business model. Most internet commerce in the industry is limited to swag, production equipment and glassware.

Answer (score 2):

No.  As it is an interstate transaction, the applicable laws of sales are the Federal Laws, which still classify it as an illegal substance, and thus, will prosecute for charges related to interstate sales.  In so far as I am aware, all cannabis grown for consumption (as opposed to other utilities, like Hemp rope and oils, which I'm fuzzy on the legal specifics) must be grown and sold within the same state to avoid Federal issues.

That said, if a non-Colorado resident was vacationing in Colorado, they could purchase cannabis for consumption while in Colorado and provided they keep it in the state, are allowed to use it... However, they may not take it home with them (This again becomes Interstate or International and the Feds have jurisdiction over that.).